# Mqtt callback wont work when activity is paused/stopped (using paho android service client)

Tags: android, service, publish-subscribe, mqtt, paho

I'm using paho android service client to receive messages from a server using Mqtt. the application works fine for both sending and receiving when activity is running but any messages published when application is not running is not received and my Callback class won't run.

I believe it might be an issue with the context and that my Callback is tied to my activity context, or i would need to somehow wake my application so that it would write the message to database then sleep again.

here's my implementation of MqttCallback:

```
public class Callback implements MqttCallback{

private Context context;
private static final String TAG = "MQTT";

public Callback(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
    MQTTClient.reconnect(); 
}

@Override
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
}

@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    Log.i(TAG,"mesage arrived");
    //update database and store message
}
```

and heres my client instantiation:

```
    client = newMqttAndroidClient(context,Constants.ADDRESS+Constants.PORT,
    MqttAsyncClient.generateClientId());
    client.setCallback(new Callback(context));
```

the context being sent to both is that of my MainActivity (this)

any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I am interested in the solution.

Comment: might be a bit late. but in case anyone stumbled into this question. solved this by creating a long running service and creating my callback and MqttClient inside that service. Initially I thought the paho service takes care of reviving my callback which was not the case.

Comment: @Ramin that is exactly how I have my implementation as well. I've recently started to wonder if it's worth exploring implementing the callback in a forever-worker thread as opposed to the service. A service, though "background" still runs in the process of the calling Activity, thus putting it in the UI. If your client get's flooded with messages, or the client publishes a ton of messages, this could cause some lags in the UI.